# How to prevent auto escape in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, escaping

In the docs it says:

> The only exceptions are variables that are already marked as “safe” from escaping, either by the code that populated the variable, or because it has had the safe or escape filters applied."

How does the "populated the variable" part work ? I'm actually looking for a way to declare a template tag as safe in the view. I somehow think it's not a good idea to let a designer decide. My co-worker will just add it whenever she 'thinks' it's a good idea.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Django has a subclass of strings called *safe* strings (specifically `SafeUnicode` or `SafeString`), which can be created using `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe`. When the template engine comes across a safe string it doesn't perform HTML escaping on it:

```
>>> from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> Template("{{ name }}").render(Context({'name': mark_safe('<b>Brad</b>')}))
u"<b>Brad</b>"
```

If you're writing your own template tag, you need to implement `render()` which will return a string that will be treated as safe, meaning you have to handle any escaping necessary yourself. However if you're writing a template filter, you can set the attribute `is_safe = True` on the filter to avoid auto escaping of the returned value, e.g.

```
@register.filter
def myfilter(value):
    return value
myfilter.is_safe = True
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping for more details.

Comment: In Django 2.2 (probably also earlier versions...) you can do `@register.filter(is_safe=True)`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping

Answer (score 6):

You could call `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe` and pass you variable

```
...
return direct_to_template('my-template.html', {'safe_var': mark_safe('<script>alert("");</script>')})
```

In template it will be printed without escaping (alert will popup). Though auto-escape is really a great feature that will save you from some bad things.