# HTML code shows as text in template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a template like:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% if post %}
    <p> Post id: {{post.id}} </p>
    Post title: {{post.post_title}} 
    Post: {{post.post_body | safe}} 

{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

my `post.post_body` is

```
<code> Hello World! </code>
```

The problem is, when the page is rendered code tags also shows up, they are not rendering as HTML tags. If i check rendered html, i see:

```
<p>&lt;code&gt; Hello World! &lt;/code&gt;</p>
```

How can i render those tags as HTML tags?

Comment: how you Setthings path looks?

Comment: @Ethaan if you mean settings.py file, it's under project directory. In different directory.

Comment: I had suggested turning autoescape off. Since that was ineffective I have withdrawn my answer. Thanks for trying though. Have a look at [How to prevent auto escape in Django templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774902/how-to-prevent-auto-escape-in-django-templates) for a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: The output shown does not match the template - only `post.id` is within `<p>...</p>` tags but you've shown `post.post_body` in paragraph tags. Given this inconsistency, and the fact that the `safe` filter should prevent escaping, how certain are you that `post.post_body` is really set to unescaped `<code> Hello World! </code>`? Is it possible that the string has already been escaped in the `post` object, or the context? Could you show the code from the view that renders this template?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `safe` filter, you should wrap variable with tags `{% autoescape off %}` and `{% endautoescape %}`.

Comment: I had suggested this early on, but upon being told that it was unhelpful, withdrew my answer.